# Selenium how to disable chrome Save Address prompt?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, prompt, disable

Selenium how to disable chrome Save Address prompt?

It does not affect testing. But it affects video recordings for demo by running selenium test.

How to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

To disable *notification* in `Chrome` browser client take you can use a *setExperimentalOption()* passing there a *HashMap* containing `profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications` with *Value* of `2`, as following:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still popup "Save Address" prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I found this to work in Selenium Java

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
prefs.put("autofill.profile_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```